# Boost.Geometry: How to create simple array of polygons and save tham as svg image?

Tags: c++, svg, vector, boost, boost-geometry

I look at grate library called [Boost Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) 
 I look at it but see no tutorials on working with anything at least a bit graphical. So I wonder if any one can help providing a simple tutorial on creating some `N` random poligons (random in color size and form)  and saving tham as vector image like [SVG](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG)?

Comment: This might help: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.Plot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So... solved it: on google you can find [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/faith_and_brave/20110301/1298961170) old code. It will not compile with latest boost 1.47.0. So you will try to fix it and you'd get [here](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/group__envelope.html) for example on some outdated docs... so long story short here is what you shall do to make it work:

Download 3 code files for [`boost/geometry/extensions/io/svg/`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/geometry/extensions/io/svg/), they are header only so no wories here.

and now you can compile fixed, updated for current boost code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/svg/write_svg.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/envelope.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/io/svg/write_svg.hpp>


template <typename Geometry1, typename Geometry2>
void create_svg(std::string const& filename, Geometry1 const& a, Geometry2 const& b)
{
    typedef typename boost::geometry::point_type<Geometry1>::type point_type;
    std::ofstream svg(filename.c_str());

    boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point_type> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
    mapper.add(a);
    mapper.add(b);

    mapper.map(a, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-width:2");
    mapper.map(b, "opacity:0.8;fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,128,0);stroke-width:4;stroke-dasharray:1,7;stroke-linecap:round");
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::assign;


    boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > ring;
    ring +=
        boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(4.0, -0.5), boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(3.5, 1.0),
        boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(2.0, 1.5), boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(3.5, 2.0),
        boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(4.0, 3.5), boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(4.5, 2.0),
        boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(6.0, 1.5), boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(4.5, 1.0),
        boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>(4.0, -0.5);


     boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > box;
     boost::geometry::envelope(ring, box); 
    std::cout
        << "make_envelope:"
        << boost::geometry::dsv(box)
        << std::endl;

    create_svg("make_envelope.svg", ring, box);
}
```

this will draw this:

[image]

(not image but vector svg file openable in google chrome=)) So this is how to create SVG file from vector in C++=)

Comment: +1 ty for posting this!  Looks like the boost::geometry is still in transition as that directory still doesn't exist in 1.48.

Comment: @Rella Is there a corresponding a read() operation? That is, if I draw a polygon in svg, how can I read it into a boost::geometry::model::polygon?

Comment: modern versions of boost don't work without a little modification. I'll edit this answer with those.

Answer (score 0):

For versions of `boost >= 1.54` we now official support from the library under [boost::geometry::io::svg](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/io/svg.html).

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>


namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

using Point2D = bgm::d2::point_xy<double>;
using Polygon2D = bgm::polygon<Point2D>;


template <typename Geometry>
void create_svg(std::string const& file_path, Geometry const& geometry, std::string const& style) {
    using PointType = typename bg::point_type<Geometry>::type;
    std::ofstream svg_file(file_path.c_str());
    bg::svg_mapper<PointType> mapper(svg_file, 400, 400);
    mapper.add(geometry);
    mapper.map(geometry, style);
}

Polygon2D create_polygon(Point2D const& p1, Point2D const& p2, Point2D const& p3, Point2D const& p4) {
    // NOTE: For closed poly first point equal to the last
    return {{p1, p2, p3, p4, p1}};
}

int main() {
    auto const& polygon = create_polygon({0., 0.}, {0., 4.}, {7., 4.}, {7., 0.});
    std::string style{"fill-rule:nonzero;fill-opacity:0.5;fill:yellow;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;"};
    create_svg("image.svg", polygon, style);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives us

[image]

Full code for playing is available [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:32,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:32,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:32,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:32,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfstream%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cboost/geometry.hpp%3E%0A%0A%0Anamespace+bg+%3D+boost::geometry%3B%0Anamespace+bgm+%3D+boost::geometry::model%3B%0A%0Ausing+Point2D+%3D+bgm::d2::point_xy%3Cdouble%3E%3B%0Ausing+Polygon2D+%3D+bgm::polygon%3CPoint2D%3E%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Geometry%3E%0Avoid+create_svg(std::string+const%26+file_path,+Geometry+const%26+geometry,+std::string+const%26+style)+%7B%0A++++using+PointType+%3D+typename+bg::point_type%3CGeometry%3E::type%3B%0A++++std::ofstream+svg_file(file_path.c_str())%3B%0A++++bg::svg_mapper%3CPointType%3E+mapper(svg_file,+400,+400)%3B%0A++++mapper.add(geometry)%3B%0A++++mapper.map(geometry,+style)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0APolygon2D+create_polygon(Point2D+const%26+p1,+Point2D+const%26+p2,+Point2D+const%26+p3,+Point2D+const%26+p4)+%7B%0A++++//+NOTE:+For+closed+poly+first+point+equal+to+the+last%0A++++return+%7B%7Bp1,+p2,+p3,+p4,+p1%7D%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+const%26+polygon+%3D+create_polygon(%7B0.,+0.%7D,+%7B0.,+4.%7D,+%7B7.,+4.%7D,+%7B7.,+0.%7D)%3B%0A++++std::string+style%7B%22fill-rule:nonzero%3Bfill-opacity:0.5%3Bfill:yellow%3Bstroke:black%3Bstroke-width:2%3B%22%7D%3B%0A++++create_svg(%22image.svg%22,+polygon,+style)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.53620352250489,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27175%27)),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.46379647749511,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).